# FindTask does not work - 304 not modified

Tags: arcgis-server, query-task, find, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I use 3.16 and I have got some problem.

When I try to execute FindTask

```
        require(["esri/tasks/FindTask", "esri/tasks/FindParameters"], function (FindTask, FindParameters) {
            console.log("Hello from FindTask");
            var findtask = new FindTask({
                url: "someWorkingURL"
            });
            var findparams = new FindParameters();
            findparams.returnGeometry = true;
            findparams.layerIds = layersIDs;
            findparams.searchFields = ["MYVALUE"];

            findparams.searchText = data["myValue"];
            findtask.execute(findparams, drawObject, drawError);
        });
```

I do not see writing "Hello from FindTask". In ArcGIS Manager I see that querying is allowed.

Where may problem be?

P.S. In network page in Firefox i see "304 not modified"

Answer: I changed hosts of my app http-requests to localhost and everything is good now. Also, I downloaded JS API and set localhost as host there. 
I think, the problem was in *mismatched hosts*: I've deployed my app on my computer with corporate IP address as host but HTTP-requests have gone to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I changed hosts of my app http-requests to localhost and everything is good now. Also, I downloaded JS API and set localhost as host there. I think, the problem was in *mismatched hosts*: I've deployed my app on my computer with corporate IP address as host but HTTP-requests have gone to localhost.